# I want to ask a question about London areas

Tags: expressions

I am an international student; I study in London. I am looking for a place to stay so that I can complete my dissertation. I plan to find a place where is near to London. I am looking for a quiet and safe place. But I have no idea which town/area I should lookup. Is there anyone can give me any advice?

Kind Regards,

Donald

Comment: This is a travel question and is not about the English language so it is off topic.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. There's [travel.SE] right here.

Comment: Avoid Croydon at all costs.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks very much. ^ ^